# Pylance analyzing every Jupyter cells after every change on VSCode and never works

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, pylance

I am working on a Jupyter Notebook on VSCode, and I have an issue which is that after every edit I make in an existing or new cell, Pylance re-analyzes the whole file (every single cell), which makes it unusable most of the time. Actually, sometimes it isn't even analyzing, but the autocomplete just doesn't want to work.

I checked and everything is up-to-date, I also tried to re-install Pylance and Jupyter. I don't know if it is important to be precise but I am working on an anaconda env, and I added its path to the python.autoComplete.extraPaths and python.analysis.extraPaths.

Does anyone have an idea of what the issue is? Thanks for reading.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, you could submit the issue to the developers in [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter).

Comment: if you raise an issue ticket, please ping me with a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you can try restarting VSCode or using VSCode command `Developer: Reload Window`.

Comment: I tried that, and during the first seconds Pylance works again, but then stops working.